# How do I print "$$" without printing the pid?

Tags: perl

I am trying to store a comment in $comment, which can be anything.
say:

```
GetOptions(
'-C=s'   => \$comment,
);
```

Suppose the user enters "Hello $$$$". when i try to print $comment or use it somewhere else it is taking the pid of current running process.

```
print "$comment\n";
```

The output is:

```
Hello 109236109236
```

Is there a way to print the content as it is?
for example:

```
Hello $$$$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not Perl as can be seen in the following snippet:

```
$foo = 'Hello$$$$';
print "$foo"   # prints 'Hello$$$$'
```

The problem is instead the shell the user is using. It expands the `$$` inside the command line argument to the pid and then gives the changed argument to the application:

```
shell$ app.pl -C Hello$$$$     # calls app.pl with HelloPIDPID
```

If you don't want this the user has to properly quote the argument

```
shell$ app.pl -C 'Hello$$$$'   # calls app.pl with 'Hello$$$$'
```

Again, nothing about this can be done in Perl since Perl only gets the already expanded argument.

Comment: Thank you for the info, It helped a lot.